# How to loop through controls and negate a certain tool

Tags: c#, controls

I'd like to loop through my controls and make an `IF` conditional, but instead using this:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
    {
      if(c is TextBox) {}
    }
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
if(!c is TextBox){}
```

you know ? I'd like to get into the loop only if the control `C` is `DIFFERENT` of a TextBox.  Of course the method I tried `!` does not work with `Controls`. How may I deny that ?

Comment: just use `if(!(c is TextBox))`

Comment: Yep, `!c` wont work because it cannot evaluate to true/false.  `!(c is TextBox)` will work because the expression in the parentheses can.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation. Of course, it looks so dumb now u.u
Thank you ! @Evanlewis

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro No problem.  You should consider marking Andrei's answer as the answer since he/she provided code and was the first post.

Comment: @Evanlewis I know. But I'm only able to do so after 10min ;P I still need to wait 3min ;x

Answer (score 6):

Just include condition into parenthesis:

```
if (!(c is TextBox)) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(!(c is TextBox))
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```